# Injection of Catalan objects into 3-connected planar graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, catalan-numbers, planar-graphs

Let $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ be the $n$-th Catalan number, counting, for example, the number of (rooted) triangulations of the $(n+2)$-gon.

Let $P_n$ be the number of three-connected planar graphs on $n$-vertices, https://oeis.org/A000944.

If I am not mistaken, $C_{n-3} \leq P_n$ for $n\geq 4$.  Eg., there are $C_2=2$ triangulations of the $4$-gon, and $2$ three-connected planar graphs on $5$ vertices.

Is there a nice injection?

**Update:**

Let $P_n^m$ be the number of three-connected planar graphs on $n$-vertices with $m$ edges.  In particular, $P_n^{3n-6}$ are the triangulations.

Let $C_n^m$ be the number of Dyck paths of semilength $n$ with $m$ returns, i.e., https://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000011.

Then, it seems that $C_{n-3}^{m - 2n + 3} \leq P_n^m$ for $n\geq 4$ and all $m$, or, if you prefer, $C_n^m \leq P_{n+3}^{2n+3+m}$ for $n\geq 1$.

**Variation:**

We also have, I think, $C_{n-4} \leq P_n^{3n-6}$ for $n\geq 4$.  (I had an off-by-one error in a previous version of the question.)

Is there a nice injection from $C_{n-4}$ into $P_n^{3n-6}$?

Comment: My prev. answer did not take planarity into consideration - I somehow missed that condition.

Comment: Can you do the following: take a triangulation of an n-gon and then add a cone vertex (a vertex connected to all the other ones), to get a 3-connected planar graph?

Comment: Yes, but I think that this is not injective. Perhaps it works if we join the cone vertex to all the original vertices except the root?

Comment: @MartinRubey: why is it non-injective? Is A000944 counting labeled graphs, or isomorphism classes of graphs?

Comment: A000944 is counting isomorphism classes, i.e., unlabelled graphs.

Comment: Yes, I meant with the adjustment. If the root vertex and it's two neighbors in the n-gon form a triangle, the adjusted cone construction is not three connected.